# jest: how to mock a variable that just is a boolean?

Tags: jestjs

how can you mock a value for a variable?  I tried `mockReturnValue` and `mock` but I think I am doing something wrong with how I am using it.

*main.js*

```
const isAvailable = cond1 || cond2 || cond3; // return boolean;
```

*test/main.js*

```
isAvailable.mock('true'); // tried this
isAvailable = jest.mockReturnValue('true'); // trie this as well
```

Comment: The question lacks the context. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your case, including all relevant files. It's unknown what happens with isAvailable . It's possible that it cannot be mocked.

Comment: Why do you think you need to mock anything here?

Answer (score 1):

`jest.fn().mockReturnValue(true)`

Comment: even if it's not a function?

Comment: Yeah, it's just how you mock values in jest. They have an extensive API, where you can mock a value only once, or a resolved / rejected value.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. That gives a mock function that returns true, but is not a boolean itself.